# CPU clarification in vCenter

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware, vmware-vsphere, central-processing-unit, dell-poweredge

So i'm running a lab on a Dell PE R410 2 X 4C 2.26Ghz, this evening I saw that vCenter is showing that the processor is @ 2.27Ghz.  It's not that big of a deal but was curious as to why there is that extra 10Mhz in the stats for the server?  Is there a technical reason for this that i'm missing or is it just vCenter not quite pulling the correct information?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it. It's just a rounding issue... 2267MHz is usually represented as 2.27GHz

From `dmidecode` on a similar system:

```
Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5520 @ 2.27GHz
        Voltage: 1.4 V
        External Clock: 133 MHz
        Max Speed: 4800 MHz
        Current Speed: 2267 MHz
```

Or look at how a 2.8GHz CPU is represented...

[image]